# Functions used in ASF instead of IODIR, IOSET, PORTD

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, atmel

I have programmed microcontroller before and used instructions like IODIR, IOSET, PORTD, DDRD and etc. I am now using Arduino Due which have the ATSAM3X8E Cortex M3 microcontroller. Iam programming the Arduino Due using Atmel Studio 6. I have figured out that the SAM3X microcontroller don't use the IODIR, IOSET, PORTD. My question now is if somebody now what functions corresponds to IODIR, IOSET and PORTD. I am using also the Atmel Software Framework (ASF) to program.

For example how do you do this using Atmel Software Framework (ASF):
PORTD &= ~(1 << RS);

Answer (score 0):

Check out the gpio driver in the asf under sam/drivers/gpio.  It contains functions like `gpio_set_pin_high(PIN)` and `gpio_set_pin_low(PIN)` that are used to control IO pins.